# IIS 7 query string length

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I`m using Asp Net Mvc 4 Web Api and I need to make request with querystring length > 2000 symbols

I`ve allready set maxQueryStringLength="10000" parameter in web.config.
Everything works well on my developer machine
On IIS it works only if querystring < 2000 symbols,
but if querystring > 2000 symbols I get an error: 404 Not Found

Any considerations?

Comment: That is a beastly querystring and not what it was meant for. Is it not possible to use POST instead?

Comment: @TheZ you right. It`s not well. I`ll think about POST.

Comment: A post would certainly be more reliable. The max querystring length is also property of the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you also set the maxUrl length?

> maxUrl    Optional uint attribute.
>
> Specifies maximum length of the URL, in bytes.
>
> The default value is 4096.

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits

Comment: Not maxUrl, but "Maximum query string (Bytes)" in Request Filtering. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Late for the party but, here is the three points we have changed to get rid of it:

In `web.config`, add `httpRuntime` tag the attribute `maxQueryStringLength`:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" />
</system.web>
```

Again in `web.config`, add `requestLimits` tag the attribute `maxQueryString`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
<system.webServer>
```

If still no cure, from the IIS config, in `ISAPI Filters` section, remove the  `UrlScan` filter. This last one did the trick in my case. But, beware, it brings a security risk.